# CASE statement with specific positions in a SQL string?

Tags: sql

I'm testing a database for dates that are incorrectly formatted as having months or years with a 0 value. For example, 20190001 would be a date corresponding to January 2019, with a 0 value for the day. 20191500 would be a date with a 0 value in the month category. I am trying to query a database to see how many incorrectly formatted values there are by selecting the values of the substring and using them in a CASE statement. Could you help me find a better way to do this? Here is my code:

```
SELECT  'date' as test,
        (CASE WHEN 
            (substring(cy.date,7, 2) OR substring(cy.date, 5, 2))
                IS NULL
                THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
            AS incorrect_format

        (CASE WHEN
            (substring(cy.date,7, 2) OR substring(cy.date, 5, 2))   
                IS NOT NULL
                THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
            AS correct_format

FROM data.cy_dates cy
```

Comment: Please tag with the database you are using.

Comment: If you can add your dbms as well

Comment: and you dont need for `case when not null` rather add `else then.. `

Answer (score 0):

Well, for these particular examples, use `like`:

```
(case when cy.date like '____00__' then 0
      when cy.date like '______00' then 0
      else 1
 end)
```

Of course, there could be other issues with the date as well.